# HTTPd 2.4 (Centreon 19.10 ISO - Centos 7)

Tags: apache

I have downloaded and been using the latest version of centreon monitoring.

I want to install cacti, and phpmysql.

I have both installed, but trying to get both running is causing a headache.

The issue is down to httpd/apache configs.
"
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource."

Several years/before kids could have nailed this in minutes, but the kids have killed my brain :(

folder locations are correct (even set them temp as 777 to attempt to fix, rolled back
Config I am attempting to use for cacti:

```
Alias /cacti /var/www/html/cacti

<Directory /var/www/html/cacti/>
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                # httpd 2.4
                Require all granted
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                # httpd 2.2
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from all
        Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
        </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Config attempting for phpmysql

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/PhpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/PhpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted 
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      #Apache 2.4   
         Order Allow,Deny
         Allow from all
    Require ip 192.168.1.0/24
    Require ip ::1  
   </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
      #Apache 2.2
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from all
    Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Any thoughts or help would be great,

Thanks again